# How to change from date format from object ( 16-04-2017 ) to DateTime format of (2017-04-16) in pandas?

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbFKr.png)

How to change from date format from object ( 16-04-2017 ) to DateTime format of (2017-04-16) in pandas

Comment: Please post text/code, not images. that makes it much easier for the community to provide good answers. Also make sure to add what you tried which didn't work / give the expected result, see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use to_datetime() e.g

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(df[date_field],format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: a simple `df['application_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['application_date'])` should be sufficient

Comment: This was not giving me correct format. You can see in the image attached.